# Big trouble with Kotlin libraries

Tags: android, kotlin, libraries, compatibility, licensing

i've build an android application in Kotlin, and it use these libraries :

...

```
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //Add Text Recognition Google ML Library
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common:18.0.0'
    implementation("info.debatty:java-string-similarity:2.0.0")
```

...

My doubt is this.

These libraries are open source and royalty free or at some point I may get a payment request from google or someone else.
This is because we cannot remove an application from the user's smartphone but only from the Play Store, so before publishing it I need confirmation of licenses and royalties on the use of these libraries.

Here below the complete list of the licenses :

> ```
> https://opensource.org/license/mit/
> https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
> https://developer.android.com/studio/terms
> https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
> https://github.com/mojohaus/animal-sniffer/blob/master/LICENSE
> https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/refs/heads/main/README.chromium
> https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
> https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
> https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/LICENSE
> https://github.com/amaembo/jsr-305/blob/master/ri/LICENSE
> https://github.com/google/jsinterop-annotations/blob/master/LICENSE
> ```

**KOTLIN LIBRARIE THAT EXTRACT ALL THIS LICENSE - START**

> ```
> https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/license/LICENSE.txt
> https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-deps-trove4j/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
> https://www-archive.mozilla.org/mpl/npl-1.1
> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/1.1/
> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/
> https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
> https://github.com/stephengold/asm/blob/master/LICENSE
> https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt
> https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
> ```

**KOTLIN LIBRARIE THAT EXTRACT ALL THIS LICENSE - END**

> ```
> https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms
> https://developers.google.com/terms
> https://developer.android.com/studio/terms.html
> ```

I have listed the third party dependencies from my app using the OSS Licenses plugin (https://johncodeos.com/how-to-list-third-party-dependencies-licenses-in-your-android-app/).
When this plugin is run, it returns all the libraries it finds in my app, even if they seem too many for an app that takes photos and performs ocr.
One such library is called Kotlin, clicking on this library shows me a long text with a mix of incompatible NPL and GPL licenses.....(see above between the bolded sentences)

I do not understand why.

Many thanks
Massimo

Comment: Legal questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. You do seem to be confusing licenses for the code libraries you’re using in your app and the ones used for compilers and IDE plug-ins, which are irrelevant to your concerns as long as you aren’t bundling them into your app.

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04,
thanks for the answer, if it's so how can i get only the libraries used in my app and not the libraries used for compilers and IDE pug-ins?
The  OSS Licenses plugin, extracts everythings...

Comment: I’ve only ever done this manually. I go to the GitHub site of each library I’m using to see the license, and to see which dependencies it is using, and repeat

Comment: That is, all the implementation in my app gradle?

Many thanks

Comment: that is:


  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

Comment: and

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //Add Text Recognition Google ML Library
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common:18.0.0'

Comment: implementation("info.debatty:java-string-similarity:2.0.0")

Comment: Yes. Anything starting with `androidx` is just part of Android Jetpack. For the rest, you may need to dig a bit.

Comment: Ok, so i've to check "only" the libraries in gradle starting with the comand implementation?

Many thanks
Massimo

Comment: Only the dependencies used by your product. You don’t need to credit the unit test libraries or gradle plug-ins. But you should check transitive dependencies, the libraries used by those libraries, and so on.

Comment: @Tenfour04
So, i've not to consider these list below:
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.android.library'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'

But i've not understand when you say :  check transitive dependencies, the libraries used by those libraries

i've to check each import in each kt file?

Many thanks
Massimo

Comment: One library might be using another library, therefore that transitive dependency is also used by your app and its license would apply and it should be credited in your app. From  what you've listed above, I don't *think* that impacts you. But as an example, if you used the Retrofit library, it has OkHttp as a dependency, so technically apps that use Retrofit should also credit OkHttp.

Comment: Ok,
but foe example, i've this libraries : androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha07 , i0ve tried to search its license, but i've found nothing

Thank
Massimo

Comment: This could be a good site to see the license of my libraries?

For example of  androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha07
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.camera/camera-core/1.3.0-alpha07

i've seen : Compile Dependencies (6) , Runtime Dependencies (4) , Managed Dependencies (10)

where have i to look?

Many thanks.
Massimo

Comment: I personally would not bother looking deeper at dependencies of anything starting with `androidx` and just credit them all together as Android Jetpack. Maybe that’s not technically correct but I don’t think Google is out to do a “gotcha” with the Jetpack libraries. They make these libraries expressly for making it easier to develop for Android so the platform will have better software overall.

Comment: basically I can avoid checking the licenses of all the libraries that start with androidx.
I exclude all puglins and test libraries.
For which they remain:
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:19.0.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common:19.0.0'
     implementation("info.debatty:java-string-similarity:2.0.0")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.1'

Is that correct?

Thank
Massimo

Comment: I can't provide legal advice, but that is the way I do it. 12 years on the store with occasional interactions with Google staff about my store content and they've never had issue with how I'm crediting libraries. I don't think the Material or Play Services libraries have transitive dependencies you need to worry about either. I'm not familiar with that info.debatty one.

Comment: Many thanks @Tenfour04 ,
with your help now i've inderstand the difference between compile libraries and app libraries.
Now i'll try to check the above libraries app list to another section of stackoverflow, where i hope to find help on legal side of each of them.

Many thanks again.
Massimo

Comment: One last thing!

For example the libraries:
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha07"
Has this license reference in the Licenses section of (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.camera/camera-core/1.3.0-alpha07) , that is : 

The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
BSD License

have i well understand?

Thank
Massimo

Comment: It has two different licenses. Maybe there are a few classes in the library that use the BSD license instead of Apache for some reason. Looks like that Camera library depends on more than just Kotlin--it also uses Google Guava ListenableFuture, so that technically should be credited.

Comment: Excuse @Tenfour04 but i'm a bit confused...
I've not understand in what section i've to look to find all the licenses and its dependencies for implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.0-alpha07"..

I see:
Compile Dependencies (6)
Runtime Dependencies (4)
Managed Dependencies (10)

and Licenses

For example Google Guava ListenableFuture it's always under Apache 2.0 if i've understand, and how have i to accreditate it?

Many thanks

Comment: This is what I do. I have a menu item that opens an About this App dialog. The dialog has a message that says the app uses the following Apache 2.0-licensed libraries. Then I have a bullet list of my libraries. And I put a web link to the Apache 2.0 license, which technically is not the right way to do it (the text should be directly in my app) but I don't think anyone really cares. Credit the Compile and Runtime Dependencies and mention the licenses they use. The Managed Dependencies are really just optional parts of the library to can also include in your project.

Comment: Ok,
but the Google Guava ListenableFuture is a compile libraries (section Compile Dependencies of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.camera/camera-core/1.3.0-alpha07), you've told me that i've not to consider the compile libraries but only the runtime libraries, am i wrong?

Many thanks.
Massimo

Comment: Those are compile-time dependencies—still part of your app. I was talking about compilers. For example, you don’t have to credit the Kotlin compiler.

Comment: ok, how can i understand what are the libraries that i've to credit and which i've not to credit?
The OSS Licenses plugin, i'm using in my app has extract a lot of libraries and license, most of them under (https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt), but for the others i've many dubts.

Many thanks.
Massimo

Comment: Isn't that your original question? I think I've told you everything I know about it. I've never used the OSS Licenses plugin, so I can't speak to that. You need to follow the license terms for libraries you use *in* your software. OSS licenses generally do not state that you must credit software that you *use to create* your own software, but you can read the respective licenses to be sure. Probably the OSS License plugin lists absolutely everything because it's not trying to make legal decisions or interpretations for you, and leaves it up to you to determine.